# iptables port forward to diferent box port

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall

Hy everyone!

I have a home network, and have a DVR (provison) connected with my cameras. I can access to my dvr via internet/lan, but the dvr don't have any security options except fixed ips or ip ranges to setup. (limited setup) and i have dynamic ip... So i tough, that i "protect" a bit my dvr with the pi, and with iptables and made it so that the pi can be connected just from my country. I want to add more options after i can made it work what i want.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 180 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.69:80
  iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

added `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`

My iptables FORWARD and OUTPUT chain is on accept, the INPUT chain is on DROP only.

The connection is working, so i can reach the 192.168.1.69 boxs 80 port, i get my web login page, but after i try to log in - put my user and pass-  i get an error, that the connection failed.
Its like something can com tough the "pipe" but i don't get it what. And of course, the android app cant log in either over the pi˙s 180 port. If i go directly to dvr˙s ip and port, everything working OK.
The DVR don't have any configuration that can see that i come from another ip not the pi˙s ip.
I try to add -p udp to the nat rule but id does not helped either.
Have someone any idea?

`tcpdump host 192.168.1.69`

I got this, after i send my login information. (megatron is my rasberry pi box and kamera is the DVR)

```
21:22:49.537477 IP megatron.57040 > kamera.http: Flags [S], seq 442083250, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
21:22:49.538281 IP kamera.http > megatron.57040: Flags [S.], seq 3281539907, ack 442083251, win 14600, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 5], length 0
21:22:49.540287 IP megatron.57040 > kamera.http: Flags [.], ack 1, win 1024, length 0
21:22:49.541540 IP megatron.57040 > kamera.http: Flags [P.], seq 1:285, ack 1, win 1024, length 284: HTTP: GET /script/device_param.js HTTP/1.1
21:22:49.542319 IP kamera.http > megatron.57040: Flags [.], ack 285, win 490, length 0
21:22:50.587327 IP kamera.http > megatron.57040: Flags [P.], seq 1:93, ack 285, win 490, length 92: HTTP: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
21:22:50.587717 IP kamera.http > megatron.57040: Flags [.], seq 93:1553, ack 285, win 490, length 1460: HTTP
21:22:50.587840 IP kamera.http > megatron.57040: Flags [.], seq 1553:3013, ack 285, win 490, length 1460: HTTP
21:22:50.587962 IP kamera.http > megatron.57040: Flags [.], seq 3013:4473, ack 285, win 490, length 1460: HTTP
21:22:50.588078 IP kamera.http > megatron.57040: Flags [.], seq 4473:5933, ack 285, win 490, length 1460: HTTP
21:22:50.588200 IP kamera.http > megatron.57040: Flags [.], seq 5933:7393, ack 285, win 490, length 1460: HTTP
21:22:50.588326 IP kamera.http > megatron.57040: Flags [.], seq 7393:8853, ack 285, win 490, length 1460: HTTP
21:22:50.588446 IP kamera.http > megatron.57040: Flags [.], seq 8853:10313, ack 285, win 490, length 1460: HTTP
21:22:50.588569 IP kamera.http > megatron.57040: Flags [.], seq 10313:11773, ack 285, win 490, length 1460: HTTP
21:22:50.588694 IP kamera.http > megatron.57040: Flags [.], seq 11773:13233, ack 285, win 490, length 1460: HTTP
21:22:50.646565 IP kamera.http > megatron.57040: Flags [P.], seq 13233:13324, ack 285, win 490, length 91: HTTP
21:22:50.663756 IP megatron.57040 > kamera.http: Flags [.], ack 93, win 1023, length 0
21:22:50.663805 IP megatron.57040 > kamera.http: Flags [.], ack 1553, win 1024, length 0
21:22:50.665385 IP megatron.57040 > kamera.http: Flags [.], ack 13324, win 1024, length 0
```

Comment: It is not obvious, at least to me, what the problem is. For debugging use `sudo iptables -xvnL` and `sudo iptables -t nat -xvnL` and watch the packet counters as you try things. Note that the PREROUTING chain should only be traversed once per connection. Also use tcpdump, or wireshark if you prefer, to monitor packet level traffic on eth0.

Comment: `6      312 DNAT       tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:180 to:192.168.1.69:80` i got this

Comment: your tcpdump capture seems normal enough. Can not tell anything from one line of iptables. You have to watch the counters, all of them, in correlation to things that you try to determine if they make sense or not.

Comment: Sadly i dont understand how does it work, but what is see, that after i get my login page from 192.168.1.69:80 over the 192.168.1.4:180 port the login information get "fragmented" or does not go trough the 180 port. I see that a port is opened on the 192.168.1.4 (megatron) the 57040 port. The redirecting feature cant handle login procedure, its just redirect the megatron 180 connection to the kamera 80 port and that`s it? The login information does not go trough on that port? The -m state NEW, ESTABLISHED, RELATED option could be the maybe answer?